# Type Mismatch Error 13 when multiplying a cel using Cells function by an interger

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to multiply the value of a cell obtained from an if statement by an interger and I get the Type Mismatch 13 error. I can't figure out why.

Here's the code, the error occurs in the last line:

```
   If Worksheets("Table 0").Cells(3, 9) = "Casi siempre" Then
        Worksheets("Table 0").Cells(110, 9).Value = 4
    End If

    If Worksheets("Table 0").Cells(3, 9) = "Siempre" Then
        Worksheets("Table 0").Cells(110, 9).Value = 5
    End If
    
    Worksheets("Table 0").Cells(110, 13).Value = 2 * Worksheets("Table 0").Cells(3, 9).Value
```

Any help would be most appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hmm. According to your `If`-statements, cells(3, 9) is a String.  `2 * "Casi siempre"` is a type mismatch...

Comment: @WltrRpo: Genau das habe ich gesagt. But please stick to english on SO.

Comment: Thank you. That was the error. The cells function was calling the wrong cell.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the last line is *unconditionally* multiplying the cell's value, and that's indeed a *type mismatch* error when either of the two conditional blocks have executed.

Since the conditional blocks are mutually exclusive, consider combining them and having `Else If` and `Else` branches - or perhaps better, a `Select Case` block:

```vb
Dim tableSheet As Worksheet
Set tableSheet = Worksheets("Table 0")

Dim tableCell As Range
Set tableCell = tableSheet.Cells(3, 9)

Select Case tableCell.Value
    Case "Casi siempre"
        tableSheet.Cells(110, 9).Value = 4
    Case "Siempre"
        tableSheet.Cells(110, 9).Value = 5
    Case Else
        If IsNumeric(tableCell.Value) Then
            tableSheet.Cells(110, 13).Value = 2 * tableCell.Value
        Else
            'tableCell contains a non-numeric value that isn't suitable for multiplication.
        End If
End Select
```

Comment: Thank you Mathiu.  I'm not sure though  how I can do that with  "else" because I would like to multiply the result from the conditional blocks by two, which would be in this case either 4*2 or 5*2, and place this value on cell (110,13).

Comment: I saw my error. I was using the wrong value in the Cells function, Worksheets("Table 0").Cells(110, 9).Value is a string, and there's your type mismatch. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @DonaldBermúdez notice how declaring local variables for your `Range` objects makes this error much easier to spot ;-)